# Why does apt-get think packages "are no longer required"

Tags: apt

I ran `apt-get install raspberrypi-net-mods` on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian and got the following message:-

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  git git-man liberror-perl rsync
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

I am confused. Why does `apt-get` think these "are no longer required"? I use `rsync` often and `git` from time to time.

Would this remove these, or have they been provided elsewhere - if so how would I check?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whenever a package is installed automatically by `apt-get` because it’s a dependency of some other package, `apt-get` notes that fact; then if it notices that nothing depends on such a package any more, it will suggest that the package be removed. This is particularly useful for libraries.

That’s all that’s meant by “no longer required”: `apt-get` doesn’t know whether you’re using the packages or not, but it knows that they were installed automatically and nothing depends on them any more.

To tell `apt-get` that a package shouldn’t be considered as automatically installed, run [`apt-mark`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-mark) and mark it as manual[ly installed]:

```
apt-mark manual git rsync
```

Or install it explicitly (this won’t do anything if the latest version of the package is already installed, except mark it as manually installed):

```
apt-get install git rsync
```

Since these packages are already installed, `apt-get` won’t install them again, but it will mark them as explicitly installed and won’t suggest their removal. (If the packages aren’t the newest versions available, `apt-get` will upgrade them.)